# ASP.NET:How to make webform mobile responsive?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, responsiveness

I have ASP.NET project.I want it to change its view automatically when device is detected as mobile or as desktop.what are the ways available?please suggest some example projects.And i tried studying many tutos.But still i am unable to grasp them.So can any body suggest step by step method to do so?

Comment: You can use css3 media queries or a framework like Bootstrap and Foundation.

Comment: Browser sniffing is totally unreliable. Use RWD media queries, or as Saad suggested, Bootstrap.

Comment: i am totally new to ASP.NET.even i am hearing the word **media query** first time.so can anybody explain me clearly step by step ?with example provided?please.

Comment: Study Responsive Web Design. This will probably get closed because you do not have a "specific" question. Plus, it is not really ASP.NET-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making your webpage responsive as per device

**-->** first you need to have bootstrap in your project.

**-->** you will be having `container` in your `bootstap.css` file(*assets-->css-->bootstap.css*).

**-->** `container` will be having different kind of screen types declared by default.like

**EXAMPLE**:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

**-->** you have to use these container in your cs file.In asp.net it is ***.aspx*** extention file.for

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<div class="below-slideshow" style="padding-bottom: 0px">
            <div class="container">  <!-- NOTICE HERE:inside div declare class as container/container-fluid-->
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div>

                            <h1 class="head-line">Dashboard</h1>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

**-->** To know more about container and container fluid [http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp/%22check%20this%22)

HAPPY CODING :-)